# how can I stop the row background color expanding with the content of the drop down accordion

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

how can I stop the row background color expanding with the content of the dropdown accordion.

I need the row to stay in place and the dropdown to start under the selected row. At the moment the style of the row changes completely when myaccordion is triggered.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/less/Custom/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

function:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".myaccordion").accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true
    });

});
</script>
```

table:

```
<div>
       <table class="students" style="border-spacing: 0 8px; border-collapse: separate;">
           @foreach (var item in Model.project)
               {
                   @:<tr style="background-color:grey;-moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;">           
                   <td class="position">@item.Position</td>                        
                   <td class="myaccordion" style="width: 50%;padding-left: 10px;text-align: left;"><a href="#">@item.Name</a>
                   <div style="font-size:10px;">
                       @foreach (var name in Model.project1)
                           {   
                               <div style="-moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;width:100%;padding-top:10px">
                                   <span style="margin-left:1%; text-align: center">@name.Position</span>                                
                                   <span style="margin-left:8%; text-align: center">@name.Name</span>
                                   <span style="margin-left:10%; text-align: center">@name.Points</span>
                               </div>

                           }                            

                   </div>                                                            
              </td>
              <td style="width: 13%; text-align: center">@item.Points</td>                                               
              <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;padding-right:10px">@item.Total</td>                              
              @:</tr>                                               
          }     
      </table>                 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood right, you want a dropdown to expand without visually extending the parent row. Technically, there's no way to achieve this without cheating. if content in a cell gets bigger in height, the td starts growing as well and so does the row. i've thought of a solution for one line height cells. if you'll have more lines in one cell, this wouldn't work apparently.

So, first wrap every cell's content into a div, with visual properties of a cell - color, padding. Second, it's better to assign the "myaccordion" class to another div rather than to a td itself, this would leave us space to add a wrapper around it.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZL2c2/7/)

I reset each td padding to 0

```
td {
  padding:0px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

I added div.wrap to each cell:

```
.wrap {
   background-color:grey; 
   height:25px; /**solution for one line cell***/
}
```

I added special div.wrap1 to the cell with accordion:

```
.wrap1 {
   position:relative;
}

.wrap1:before {    
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color:grey;  
}
```

these would guarantee us the cross-td height and bg consistency for a one-line row (height:25px - to adjust). I dunno how to work it out for multi-lines in every cell, but probably only with js.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I will have multiple entries in the dropdown. But that will look alot better.